# Resetting kivy text inputs once the inputs have been saved + any other comments

Tags: python, input, kivy, reset

I'm currently making a program that logs strung racquets with a few different things that go along with the job. I'm having trouble resetting kivy text inputs after the information has been saved. The code is probably hard to read being it's slightly patchwork of my messing with things over the past few days. If you could help me to understand how to reset text inputs and any other improvements would be much appreciated - Chris - Novice

```
            import kivy
            import gspread
            from kivy.app import App
            from kivy.uix.label import Label
            from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
            from kivy.core.window import Window
            from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
            from kivy.core.window import Window
            from kivy.uix.button import Button
            from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager , Screen
            from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

            list = []

            Client = ''
            Racquet = ''
            String = ''
            Tension = ''

            scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
            creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
            client = gspread.authorize(creds)

            sheet = client.open("Stringing Log MAIN").sheet1

            def clients(instance, value):
                print(value)
                global Client
                Client = str(value[8:])
                global list
                return

            def racquets(instance, value):
                print(value)
                global Racquet
                Racquet = str(value[9:])
                global list
                return

            def strings(instance, value):
                print(value)
                global String
                String = str(value[8:])
                global list
                return

            def tensions(instance, value):
                print(value)
                global Tension
                Tension = str(value[9:])
                global list
                return

            clienttxt = open("Client", "w")
            racquettxt = open("Racquet", "w")
            stringtxt = open("String", "w")
            tensiontxt = open("Tension", "w")

            def Test(x):
                global sheet
                list.insert(0, Client)
                list.insert(1, Racquet)
                list.insert(2, String)
                list.insert(3, Tension)
                sheet.insert_row(list, 1)
                list.clear()
                return

            class MyGrid(GridLayout):
                def __init__(self, **kwargs):

                    super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
                    self.cols = 1


                    client = TextInput(text = "Client: ", write_tab = False, multiline=False)
                    client.bind(text=clients)
                    self.add_widget(client)

                    racquet = TextInput(text= "Racquet: ", write_tab = False, multiline=False)
                    racquet.bind(text=racquets)
                    self.add_widget(racquet)

                    string = TextInput(text= "String: ", write_tab = False, multiline=False)
                    string.bind(text=strings)
                    self.add_widget(string)

                    tension = TextInput(text= "Tension: ", write_tab = False, multiline=False)
                    tension.bind(text=tensions)
                    self.add_widget(tension)

                    button1 = Button(text="Submit")
                    self.add_widget(button1)
                    button1.bind(on_press=Test)



            class StringingApp(App):
                def build(self):
                    return MyGrid()


            if __name__ == "__main__":
                StringingApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save a reference to each `TextInput` in your `__init__()` method, for example:

```
self.client = TextInput(text = "Client: ", write_tab = False, multiline=False)
```

Then, move your `Test` method inside your `MyGrid` class:

```
        def Test(self, x):
            global sheet
            list.insert(0, Client)
            list.insert(1, Racquet)
            list.insert(2, String)
            list.insert(3, Tension)
            sheet.insert_row(list, 1)
            list.clear()

            # clear the TextInput widgets here
            self.client.text = ''
            return
```

And your `Button` bind becomes:

```
button1.bind(on_press=self.Test)
```

So here is the entire `MyGrid` class after my suggested changes:

```
class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1

        # save a reference to the client TextInput
        self.client = TextInput(text="Client: ", write_tab=False, multiline=False)
        self.client.bind(text=clients)
        self.add_widget(self.client)

        racquet = TextInput(text="Racquet: ", write_tab=False, multiline=False)
        racquet.bind(text=racquets)
        self.add_widget(racquet)

        string = TextInput(text="String: ", write_tab=False, multiline=False)
        string.bind(text=strings)
        self.add_widget(string)

        tension = TextInput(text="Tension: ", write_tab=False, multiline=False)
        tension.bind(text=tensions)
        self.add_widget(tension)

        button1 = Button(text="Submit")
        self.add_widget(button1)
        button1.bind(on_press=self.Test)   # bind to Test() method below

    def Test(self, x):
        global sheet
        list.insert(0, Client)
        list.insert(1, Racquet)
        list.insert(2, String)
        list.insert(3, Tension)
        sheet.insert_row(list, 1)
        list.clear()

        # clear the TextInput widgets here
        self.client.text = ''   # or set it to anything you want, handle the other TextInputs similarly
        return
```

Comment: I tried the edits you mentioned but when submit is pressed the TextInputs aren't being effected.

Comment: I have the order as class MyGrid, def Test, def __init__, within __init__ it goes super, self.client, racquet, string, tension, then all of the sections that add the widgets.

Comment: If I were to add new features, would it be worth adding a new page to the current app or create a new python program?

Comment: That an opinion based question. You would have to decide how you want your `App(s)` to work.

Comment: So I'm very confused on how the page managers and all of those work. Is there no easy way to create three pages for different aspects of the app with the way I set it up?

Comment: Have a look at [ScreenManager](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html).

Comment: Is there any way to work around using kivy language?

Comment: Cause I haven't been able to translate the code over to kivy language